# Oracle OCI ObjectStorage -- does an atomic create exists?

Tags: oracle, cloud, object-storage, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

Does ObjectStorage have any mechanism that would permit locking (such as an atomic operation to create an object such that the operation fails if the object already exists)? (edited)

Answer (score 1):

You can leverage HTTP [ifMatch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/If-Match) & ifNoneMatch semantics when creating an object.

> The If-None-Match HTTP request header makes the request conditional.
>   For GET and HEAD methods, the server will send back the requested
>   resource, with a 200 status, only if it doesn't have an ETag matching
>   the given ones. For other methods, the request will be processed only
>   if the eventually existing resource's ETag doesn't match any of the
>   values listed.

You can refer to the [API documentation](https://docs.cloud.oracle.com/iaas/api/#/en/objectstorage/20160918/Object/PutObject) for the header values, specifically the API calls out:

> The entity tag (ETag) to avoid matching. The only valid value is '*',
>   which indicates that the request should fail if the object already
>   exists. For creating and committing a multipart upload, this is the
>   entity tag of the target object. For uploading a part, this is the
>   entity tag of the target part.